Design NFA that accepts strings starting with a and ending with a or starting with b and ending in b
Also is regular expression possible for it? If yes, can someone show me both RE and NFA for this question?
This is the NFA that I designed, but I am not really confident about my answer.
NFA - starting with a and ending with a or starting with b and ending in b
Also I don't really know if regular expression for this is possible, but if it is, can someone show me how?

Your NFA is almost correct. It requires the input to have at least two symbols, but inputs with just one symbol ( or ) should also be accepted. You can just add another transition from 1 to 3:

To turn this into a regular expression, you could apply the state elimination method. This means that transitions can have regular expressions as their labels, so to indicate a transition may involve reading more than one symbol.
First replace the comma with the regular expression syntax for it: +. Eliminate the loop-edges, by using the Kleene star, and absorbing it into the incoming transitions:

Then eliminate states 2 and '2 by joining all possible pairs of incoming and outgoing transitions (in this case there is just one such pair for each of the two states):

The three alternative transitions can be merged together with the + operator:

As now we only have one transition from start to accept state, we have the final regular expression for the language:
a(a+b)*a+a+b+b(a+b)*b

Note that the order of the operands of the + operator is not significant, so you can have them in any order. For instance, this would also be OK:
b+a(b+a)*a+b(a+b)*b+a


@Yash, any feedback to this answer?
